# need to display textarea after clicking label

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on a label, just below that some TextArea should be displayed with some predefined text in it and the user shouldn't able to modify the TextArea's content.

This is how I tried :

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc2() {
      document.getElementById('showthis').style.visibility = "visible"
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <label onclick="myfunc2()">Click here</label>
    <textarea id="showthis" style="display:none">dfdsfsfasdfdsfsfasdfssdfsfasf</textarea>
  </body>

</html>
```

iam new to this html and javascript.. pls someone help me on this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this..

```
document.getElementById('showthis').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('showthis').readOnly=true;
```

**updated**

check for classname (hide).. if yes.. show the textarea and name it `show` ... else hide it and name the classname as `hide`

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myfunc2() {
 var selectedobj=document.getElementById('showthis');

  if(selectedobj.className=='hide'){  //check if classname is hide 
    selectedobj.style.display = "block";
    selectedobj.readOnly=true;
    selectedobj.className ='show';
  }else{
    selectedobj.style.display = "none";
    selectedobj.className ='hide';
 }
}
```

add a hide class to your html `textarea`.

HTML

```
 <textarea id="showthis" style="display:none" class="hide">dfdsfsfasdfdsfsfasdfssdfsfasf</textarea>​   // add a class hide
```

Comment: thanks! if i click label again it should close again, howz that possible..?

Comment: wow Thanks a lot! one more thing bro:  May I know how can i use this function .. I mean as soon as I click textarea predefined text should be copied to clickboard.. function copyToClipboard (text) { window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);

Answer (score 2):

Although you are setting `visibility:visible`, the element still has the style property `display:none` and therefore won't be displayed.

Rather than setting the `visibility` property, you should override the `display` property with `block`.

Change your function to:

```
function myfunc2() {
      document.getElementById('showthis').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! may I know how can i use this function .. I mean as soon as I click textarea predefined text should be copied to clickboard.. function copyToClipboard (text) { window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text); }

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `display` property, not the `visibility` one, so replace your following line:

```
document.getElementById('showthis').style.visibility="visible"
```

for this one:

```
document.getElementById('showthis').style.display="block"
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/VYEFz/).

Comment: Thanks! may I know how can i use this function .. I mean as soon as I click textarea predefined text should be copied to clickboard..

function copyToClipboard (text) {
  window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}

Answer (score 0):

CSS attributes `display` and `visibility` are different.

It make more sense to use `visibility` if you want to simple make the element inivisible but keep the place it occupies in the layout, leaving a blank space:

```
<textarea id="showthis" style="visibility:hidden">dfdsfsfasdfdsfsfasdfssdfsfasf</textarea>
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility

On the other hand, using `display` will hide the element but also remove it from the layout:

```
function myfunc2() {
    document.getElementById('showthis').style.display="block";
}
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

Comment: Thanks! may I know how can i use this function .. I mean as soon as I click textarea predefined text should be copied to clickboard.. function copyToClipboard (text) { window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text); }

Answer (score -2):

youre missing a

> ;

on

```
document.getElementById('showthis').style.visibility="visible"
```

also you need to change the display.style not the visibility of the element

try this one

```
document.getElementById('showthis').style.display = "block";
```

or append a visibility="false" attribute to your textarea

Comment: While your right, there should be a semi-colon there. Thats not the answer.

Comment: Yeah I now saw there is more going on there :-P Just took a quick overview

Comment: Sorry for doing so, the - is appreciated, I just dont want to give the questioner a false advice.